# Django DRF - Updating many-to-one model in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My models structure is pretty straightforward: a many to one relationship where a set of **Conditions** references one **Item** by the foreign key.

And here we have the corresponding serializers.py:

```
class ConditionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Condition
        fields = ('condition_id','name', 'left', 'operator', 'right')

 class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    conditions = ConditionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        conditions_data = validated_data.pop("conditions")
        item = Item.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for condition_data in conditions_data:
            Condition.objects.create(item=item, **condition_data)
        return item

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        conditions_data = validated_data.get('conditions', instance.conditions)
        for c in conditions_data.all():
            print(c.name)   # it correctly prints out the value
        instance.conditions.set(conditions_data.all())   # Doesn't update the instance
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('item_id', 'name', 'conditions')
```

The problem is in the **update** function:
*instance.name* is correctly updated; *instance.conditions.set(conditions_data.all())* **is not**.

No error is displayed, since the response is 200OK.

I also put the for loop printing of field of the Condition object (name) and it successfully is displayed, showing that the data is correctly read.

I've tried to address the issue removing the *read_only=True* from the ConditionSerializer, but the situation got worse since I receive the error:

*AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'all'*

Maybe the issue is related to the foreign key management.

Is there a way to solve this?

**UPDATE**: here the models

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
      
    readonly_fields=['item_id','created_on','last_updated']
     
class Condition(models.Model):
    condition_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    left = models.JSONField()
    operator = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    right = models.JSONField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name="conditions", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set their ids.

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    conditions = ConditionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    ...

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        conditions_data = validated_data.get('conditions', instance.conditions)
        condition_ids = []
        for c in conditions_data.all():
            condition_ids.append(c.id)
        instance.conditions.set(condition_ids)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't work because the argument of instance.conditions.set() is expecting a Condition instance, not the id.
I got the following error: "TypeError: 'Condition' instance expected, got UUID('1e9b73e8-7ffc-43f4-93b4-01f2c5467ac8')"

Comment: What is the primary key field? How are they connecting?

Comment: I updated the question with the models.
The primary key is condition_id (I used this one to test your code).

Comment: Then not `c.id` should be changed into `c.condition_id`